# Getting generic sizes for android development

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-screen

I'm building an app to support all android sizes what are the generic values for Small, Normal, Large and Xlarge taking into consideration the 7 and 10 inch tablet. I'd like to know the screen size not the screen resolution.

Comment: There it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [official dev doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).  Scroll down and you'll find a graphic associating generalized screen sizes (categories) with an approximate dimension (in inches).

Just be aware that screen size categories like "xlarge," for example, aren't tied to a hard number like "10 inches."  Instead, official documentation uses terms like "An xlarge screen is defined as a screen that is significantly larger than a "large" screen, such as a tablet (or something larger)..."

You can find fuzzy definitions of screen size categories [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just need a cheat sheet for this check this out:

http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/